# Java Object to Domain Class Object Conversion

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, reflection, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create an entity object using the class name as String at runtime. I tried to find and create the instance using java reflection. But, I couldn't map the Object to the respective entity class type.

**My code:**

```
public String update(String entityClassName) {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(entityName);
            Object obj = cls.newInstance();

}
```

Now, I want to change the Object obj to the respective entity type as dynamic. So, I can access the common field in the object.

**Expected:**

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(entityName);
<GivenEntityType> obj = cls.newInstance();
```

Could you pls anyone let me know? Is it possible?

Comment: Which common field? How would you know what `ClassType` is? With the code you're showing, all you can be sure is that it's an `Object`.

Comment: ClassType I referred to here is my entity class name. @Kayaman

Comment: Yeah, but what would you do with `obj` if that were possible?

Comment: Actually, I'm writing a generic REST API for Update. If it's possible then will update the obj using entityManager.getTransaction().commit(). So, the changes will be affected in the respected entities dynamically.

Comment: Well, it's not possible. You can pass in a `Class<T>` though. Then you'll have `T obj = cls.newInstance();`. But if you don't have an upper bound for `T`, it will erase to `Object` anyway, so that might not help you much.